Expectation of maximum of normal variables with different means
Given that ${X_1,...,X_n}$ are $n$ independent normal variables and $X_i \sim N(a_i,\sigma^2)$, can we show that $E[max\{X_1,...,X_n\}]$ is increasing in $\sigma$? Since $a_i$'s are not identical, the results for  order statstics of $i.i.d.$ random variables can not be used.
